# Understanding pointer array syntax

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to write a simple c program to print out the addresses of character strings in an array of character strings. Here is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *words[] = {"hello", "cruel", "world"};
    int count = sizeof(words) / sizeof(char*);

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
        printf("address: %p\n", (words+i));
        printf("address: %p\n", &(words[i])); //<- why does this work?
        printf("address: %p\n", words[i]); //<- not the same as first print?
        printf("---\n");
    }  

    return 0;
}
```

and the output:

```
address: 0x7fff043110f0
address: 0x7fff043110f0
address: 0x4006b4
---
address: 0x7fff043110f8
address: 0x7fff043110f8
address: 0x4006ba
---
address: 0x7fff04311100
address: 0x7fff04311100
address: 0x4006c0
---
```

Now this is how I understand it: `words` is a pointer to a pointer, pointing to the first address of this array of arrays.

Then `words[i]` is a pointer to an array of characters, `words[0]` pointing to the first address of "hello" and `words[1]` pointing to the first address of "cruel".

Now I am trying to print out the addresses of the strings in different ways.

The first way makes sense: (the pointer to `words` is incremented by the size of one pointer and then I print it out, formatting it as a pointer)

In the second one, what I think should be happening: `words[i]` returns a pointer to the indexed word and using `&` operator on it returns the address. But it is unclear to me how `%p` is is used for a pointer type in the first print statement and address type in the second statement.

What would make sense to me would be is if the third print statement gave the output of the second print statement. ( `(words+i)` and `words[i]` are the same in the context of pointers? )

Someone please help me clear this up. Thanks

Comment: "But it is unclear to me how %p is is used for a pointer type in the first print statement and address type in the second statement." - what do you think an "address type" is, and in particular, how do you think it differs from a pointer type?

Comment: First fix the `sizeof(char)` to `sizeof(char*)` - your first question really should have been "why am I getting more than three sets of addresses?"

Comment: @user2357112 pointer is a variable with architecture specific format to hold information about an address? clearly `ptr` and `&ptr` cannot be the same in memory. but I wish someone would just write a simple explanation instead of just asking more questions

Comment: @jhabbott yeah sorry. the reason I overlooked this is because I created a "dummy program" to illustrate my point but I was absent minded and completely overlooked the fact that I printed out  too many things. It still does not solve my issue though

Comment: `words[i]` is equivalent to `*(words+i)`, not `(words+i)`

Comment: @JS1 thanks for the answer. I had a misunderstanding of what the array subscript operator was doing. Seeing that `words[i]` = `*(words+i)` and not `(words+i)` makes my knowledge consistent. +1

Comment: `sizeof words/sizeof words[0]` will be better and less error prone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you compile your C code, you get a binary file. Without going into too much detail (i.e. I'm simplifying), this consists of some code and some data in different sections, the `.code` section and the `.data` section. It helps to think about what is in the `.data` section.

```
char *words[] = {"hello", "cruel", "world"};
```

This creates some data in your `.data` section, your compiler may do it differently to this, but I am using one-byte for `char` and 4-bytes for pointers:

```
0x00000000 'h' 'e' 'l' 'l' 'o' 0 ? ? <- Data for the "hello" string
0x00000008 'c' 'r' 'u' 'e' 'l' 0 ? ? <- etc.
0x00000010 'w' 'o' 'r' 'l' 'd' 0 ? ? <- etc.
```

The numbers on the left are the hex addresses within the data section. I have aligned each string on an 8-byte boundary, your compiler might do it differently, this is just how I chose to do it. Notice that the strings are terminated with a nil byte and the question marks represent the two additional (uninitialised) bytes before the next bit of data starts (caused by my alignment decision).

If your array were a global, you would also get this for the array:

```
0x00000018 0x00000000 <- 4-byte pointer to "hello" string
0x0000001C 0x00000008 <- 4-byte pointer to "cruel" string
0x00000020 0x00000010 <- 4-byte pointer to "world" string
```

In your code however it's not a global, it's created temporarily on the stack as you enter the function. That's why the addresses you see are so drastically different from the addresses of the string data. I'll pretend it's a global for this explanation and use the addresses above.

Don't worry that the value of your first pointer here is actually `NULL`. These values change in your running program, depending on what other `.data` your program is linked with and where your program is loaded into memory. The point is, the values I use here to explain are relative to your `.data` section.

Now `words` is as you say, a pointer to pointer. The value of `words` is `0x00000018` - it points to the start of your array (see above).

```
int count = sizeof(words) / sizeof(char*);
```

`sizeof(words)` is 12 (look at the data above), `sizeof(char*)` is 4, so count is 3.

Now here's what you need to understand about pointer arithmetic in C:

The compiler knows the size of the thing pointed at, and addition works in multiples of that size. Considering `words + i` - the compiler knows that words points to a pointer, and the size of a pointer is 4, therefore because `words` equals `0x00000018`, `words + 1` is equal to `0x0000001C`.

Now `words[i]` is the same as `*(words + i)` - this means the contents of `(words + i)`. When `i = 1` `(words + i)` will be `0x0000001C`, and looking at the data section, the contents of that address (which the compiler knows is a 4-byte pointer) is `0x00000008`. This is a pointer to the `"cruel"` string.

Your other experiment was with `&words[i]` - this is the same as `words + i`, it is the address of the element in the array, not what it points at.

Since the pointers in the `words` array point to `char` then `words[2][1]` would be calculated like this:

```
// First get words[2]
char *words2 = *(words + 2) <- Contents of 0x00000020 as char*
// words2 now holds 0x00000010 - the address of the "world" string
char result = *(words2 + 1)
// result now holds 'o'
```

Notice that where `words` is a pointer to pointer, `words2` above is a pointer to `char` so `words2 + 1` is `0x00000011` - it has added 1 because the `sizeof(char)` is 1. And the contents of `0x00000011` is `'o'`. If you want the address of that `'o'` character you could do `&words[2][1]` and you'd get `0x00000011`.

Answer (score 0):

`words[i]` is doing what it is supposed to -- returning the i-th element of the array -- it is pointing to where the i-th string actually lives.

`words[0]` is `0x4006b4` because that's where the `h` in `hello` lives.  And notice that `words[0]`, `words[1]`, and `words[2]` are all 6 apart.  That's because each of your words is 6 characters long (5 "real" characters and the trailing null).

`(words + i)` is telling you where in memory *the i-th element of the array lives*.  Notice those are 8 apart.  That's because the length of a pointer is 8 bytes on your system.  `words` is a pointer that points to the first element in the array.  Remember that when you do pointer arithmetic it is implicitly using the size of the type when incrementing.  So `words + i` doesn't mean "base address plus i bytes".  It means "base address plus `i*sizeof(type)` bytes".  Here the type is a pointer, and its size is 8 bytes.

`&(words[i])` is the same as `(words + i)` because the first expression is saying "give me the address of the i-th element of the array lives".  Which is the same thing `(words + i)` is doing -- because that's how the C/C++ language spec says arrays get laid out.